# Unable to upgrade python 3.8 from 3.7.7 in macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, homebrew

I am getting error when I try

```
brew install python3
```

[image: python 3.7.7 is already installed]

Comment: Please post your error message as text, not an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the warning said it all. `brew link python3` will give you `python 3.7.7`.

If you like to use `python 3.8`, you can use `brew install python@3.8` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach to manage Python versions is to follow [Moshe Zadka's](https://opensource.com/users/moshez) recommendations:

1. Install Python environment manager [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv):

```
$ brew install pyenv
```

2. Install version version as you require using pyenv install python-version, e.g:

```
$ pyenv install 3.8.3
```

3. Set your global default version: using pyenv global python-version, e.g:

```
$ pyenv global 3.8.3
```

4. Add this version to your configuration file (`.zshrc` or `.bash_profile` which ever you use) to work correctly, e.g:

```
$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Your configuration file will then be updated with the following:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Then you're good to go.

-enjoy Python!

Comment: On MacBook OS Ventura, `pyenv install 3.8.3` resulted in some type of error after a while, `ret = sendfile(in, out, offset, &sbytes, &sf, flags);`

Comment: `pyenv install 3.8` worked though